# Sum Vertically for a By Condition

Tags: sas

I checked out this previous post [(LINK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759950/summing-vertically-across-rows-under-conditions-sas/) for potential solution, but still not working. I want to sum across rows using the ID as the common identifier. The `num` variable is constant. The `id` and `comp` the two variables I want to use to creat a `pct` variable, which = sum of [`comp` = 1] / `num`

Have:

```
id  Comp    Num
1   1       2
2   0       3
3   1       1
2   1       3
1   1       2
2   1       3
```

Want:

```
id  tot  pct
1   2    100
2   3    0.666666667
3   1    100
```

Currently have:

```
proc sort data=have;
    by id;
run;

data want;
    retain tot 0;
  set have;
    by id;
        if first.id then do;
            tot = 0;
            end;
        if comp in (1) then tot + 1;
            else tot + 0;
        if last.id;
            pct = tot / num;            
        keep id tot pct; 
        output;
run;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use SQL for things like this.  You can do it in a Data Step, but the SQL is more compact.

```
data have;
input id  Comp    Num;
datalines;
1   1       2
2   0       3
3   1       1
2   1       3
1   1       2
2   1       3
;
run;

proc sql noprint;
create table want as
select id, 
    sum(comp) as tot, 
    sum(comp)/count(id) as pct
from have
group by id;
quit;
```

Comment: One follow-up: Why am I losing all variables from the have data set and the output only contains the three from the sql statement?

Comment: Because the SQL statement defines which variables will be output.  The SAS documentation PROC SQL is quite good with a lot of relevant examples.  It's how I taught myself SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is a much more elegant solution to your problem :)

```
proc sort data = have;
    by id;
run;

data want; 
    do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.id);
        set have ; 
        by id ; 
        tot = sum (tot, comp) ; 
    end ; 
    pct = tot / num ; 
run;
```

I hope it is clear. I use sql too because I am new and the DOW loop is rather complicated but in your case its pretty straightforward.